# Split column into multiple rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, set-returning-functions

Suppose I have a table like this:

| subject | flag |
| --- | --- |
| this is a test | 2 |

`subject` is of type `text`, and `flag` is of type `int`. I would like to transform this table to something like this in Postgres:

| token | flag |
| --- | --- |
| this | 2 |
| is | 2 |
| a | 2 |
| test | 2 |

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use a `LATERAL` join - with [`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.35.1.1.1) in [Postgres 14+](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAFj8pRD8HOpjq2TqeTBhSo_QkzjLOhXzGCpKJ4nCs7Y9SQkuPw%40mail.gmail.com).
Minimal form:

```sql
SELECT token, flag
FROM   tbl, string_to_table(subject, ' ') token
WHERE  flag = 2;
```

The comma in the `FROM` list is (almost) equivalent to `CROSS JOIN`, `LATERAL` is automatically assumed for set-returning functions (SRF) in the `FROM` list. Why "almost"? See:

- ["invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table" in Postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597700/invalid-reference-to-from-clause-entry-for-table-in-postgres-query/34598292#34598292)

The alias "token" for the derived table is also assumed as column alias for a single anonymous column, and we assumed distinct column names across the query. Equivalent, more verbose and less error-prone:

```sql
SELECT s.token, t.flag
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL string_to_table(subject, ' ') AS s(token)
WHERE  t.flag = 2;
```

Or move the SRF to the `SELECT` list, which is allowed in Postgres (but not in standard SQL), to (almost) the same effect:

```sql
SELECT string_to_table(subject, ' ') AS token, flag
FROM   tbl
WHERE  flag = 2;
```

The last one seems acceptable since SRF in the `SELECT` list have been sanitized in Postgres 10. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

If `string_to_table()` does not return any rows (empty or null `subject`), the (implicit) join eliminates the row from the result. Use `LEFT JOIN ... ON true` to keep qualifying rows from `tbl`. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

We could also use [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), but that's slower. Regular expressions are powerful but expensive. See:

- [SQL select rows containing substring in text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832375/sql-select-rows-containing-substring-in-text-field/21832550#21832550)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

In **Postgres 13** or older use `unnest(string_to_array(subject, ' '))` instead of `string_to_table(subject, ' ')`.

Comment: I’m not very familiar with either the `LATERAL` join or with the `unnest()` function. How would you express this as a lateral join?

Comment: @Manngo: This *is* a lateral join, just with short syntax. Verbose equivalent:  `SELECT * FROM tbl t CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(t.subject, ' ')) AS s(token);` Ample explanation in the linked answers.

Comment: Thanks. I always understood the `… , …` syntax to be a simple cross join.

Comment: For functions, it's `cross join lateral` automatically.

Answer (score 42):

I think it's not necessary to use a join, just the `unnest()` function in conjunction with `string_to_array()` should do it:

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(subject, ' ')) as "token", flag FROM test;

token | flag                                                                                                   
-------+-------                                                                                                  
this   |     2                                                                                                   
is     |     2                                                                                                   
a      |     2                                                                                                   
test   |     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex split to table function including lateral join,

```
SELECT s.token, flag
FROM   tbl t, regexp_split_to_table(t.subject, ' ') s(token)
WHERE  flag = 2;
```

Refer to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-string.html
for the function details