# SQL: how to query a set of data and count how many matched string in a given string list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I build a simple question-answer system.

In my database, there are three tables:

```
question (
  id         int
  question varchar(200)
  answer_id  int  /* foreign key mapping to answer.id */
);

answer (
  id  int
  answer    varchar(500)
)

question_elements (
    id    int
    seq   int    /*vocabulary in question location */
    question_id    int  /** foreign key mapping to question.id */
    vocabulary  varchar(40)
)
```

Now I have a question:

```
What approach should a company adopt when its debt ratio is higher than 50% and wanna continue to get funding ?
```

So in table question, a record is:

```
question {
  id: 1,
  question:"What approach should a company adopt when its debt ratio is higher than 50% and wanna continue to get funding ?",
  answer_id:1
}
```

In table question_elements

```
question_elements [
  {
    id: 1,
    seq: 1,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "what"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    seq: 2,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "approach"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    seq: 3,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "should"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    seq: 4,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "a"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    seq: 5,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "company"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    seq: 6,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "adopt"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    seq: 7,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "when"
  },
  ....
  ....
  {
    id: 19,
    seq: 19,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "get"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    seq: 20,
    question_id: 1,
    vocabulary: "funding"
  }
]
```

Now, when a user inputs:

```
What action does a company should do when it wanna get more funding with high debt ratio
```

My idea is to split the above statement into a string list, and execute a SQL query in order to count the matched string in table question_elements by giving  the above string list.

What is the SQL statement in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: are you using json fields or that is your way of show us the data?

Comment: Looks like you have two question. One is perform split by `" "` and the other is see how many matchs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split column into multiple rows in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419993/split-column-into-multiple-rows-in-postgres)

Comment: What are the output columns you are looking for?

Comment: If think i understand you, try my answer when you can.

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza, the json fields are just to show you the data.
And spliting by " " is already done. so the last problem is to count how many matchs

Comment: Adish, my idea is, let's say, there are now 10 question-answer pairs in database. A user inputs a question, and I split his/her question by " " into a list. In database, If I found that the third question's elements match count is the most, then I can say that the user could be asking the third question in database, so I can show him/her the third question's answer. Well, I know this logic may not be the best. But the first check point is that I need to know the match count for each question in the database. So I need to know how to build the SQL.

Comment: @wureka - In MS SQL I would do it like this: Step 1 Make a subquery to split the user input on space. Step 2 Join this subquery to question_element table on question_element.vocabulary and group by questionid and get a sum of the matches and pick the top 1 after putting them in desc order.
I can send you a script that works in MS SQL if it helps.

Comment: @wureka instead of loading json why not use normal table format? or even better create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ that way we can work with real data and give you a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want something like this:

```
WITH answer AS (
    SELECT 
        'What action does a company should do when it wanna get more funding' AS a
),
question AS (
    SELECT 'what' AS q
    UNION ALL SELECT 'should'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'a'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'company'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'do'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'when'
)
SELECT COUNT(result)
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array(CAST(a AS VARCHAR),' ')) AS result
    FROM answer
) AS tbaux
WHERE result IN (select CAST(q AS VARCHAR) FROM question);
```

Without Text Capitalization, and some explanations:

```
SELECT COUNT(result)
FROM (                                                 --count how many lines have in the subquery
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array(CAST(a AS VARCHAR),' ')) AS result        --this break the user input in one word per line, excluding ' '
    FROM answer
) AS tbaux                                                                  --name of the subquery
WHERE upper(result) IN (select upper(CAST(q AS VARCHAR)) FROM question);    --upper turns lowercase letters in uppercase, only the line who match will remain to the COUNT()
```

This counts how many words from the user input is in the question table (in your case `question_elements`)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4095/0

Answer (score 0):

The `question_elements` table is not necessary.

```
with ui(ui) as (
    values ('What action does a company should do when it wanna get more funding with high debt ratio')
)
select id, count(*) as matches, question
from
    (
        select id, question, regexp_split_to_table(question, '\s+') as word
        from question
    ) q
    inner join
    regexp_split_to_table((select ui from ui), '\s+') ui(word) using (word)
group by 1, 3
order by matches desc
```