# Get each <tag> in String - stackexchange database

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions, dataexplorer

Mockup code for my problem:

```
SELECT Id FROM Tags WHERE TagName IN '<osx><keyboard><security><screen-lock>'
```

#### The problem in detail

I am trying to get tags used in 2011 from apple.stackexchange data. [(this query)](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/revision/416382/531466/tag-changes-in-2011)

As you [can see](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/revision/416382/531435/tag-changes-in-2011), tags in tag changes are stored as plain text in the `Text` field.
[image: example output with stackexchange tags]

```
<tag1><tag2><tag3>
<osx><keyboard><security><screen-lock>
```

How can I create a unique list of the tags, to look them up in the `Tags` table, instead of this hardcoded version:

```
SELECT * FROM Tags
  WHERE TagName = 'osx' 
     OR TagName = 'keyboard' 
     OR TagName = 'security'
```

Here is a [interactive example](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/revision/416392/531447/search-for-a-tag-by-name).

Stackexchange uses T-SQL, my local copy is running under postgresql using Postgres app [version 9.4.5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMuX.png).

Comment: Your Postgres version is missing.

Comment: **@ErwinBrandstetter** I am thankful for any solution, independent of the version.

Comment: `WHERE TagName = ##TagName:String?osx##` isn't valid T-SQL either. I guess the DataExplorer does some query pre-processing

Comment: In the data explorer this line offers a string input field with "osx" as default value. See *Query Parameters* part of
[About Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE posthistory(post_id int PRIMARY KEY, tags text);
```

Depending on what you want exactly:

To convert the string to an array, trim leading and trailing '<>', then treat '><' as separator:

```
SELECT *, string_to_array(trim(tags, '><'), '><') AS tag_arr
FROM   posthistory;
```

To get list of unique tags for whole table (**I guess you want this**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag
FROM   posthistory, unnest(string_to_array(trim(tags, '><'), '><')) tag;
```

The implicit `LATERAL` join requires Postgres 9.3 or later.

This should be substantially faster than using regular expressions. ***If*** you want to try regexp, use [`regexp_split_to_table()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) instead of `regexp_split_to_array()` followed by `unnest()` like suggested in another answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag
FROM   posthistory, regexp_split_to_table(trim(tags, '><'), '><') tag;
```

Also with implicit `LATERAL` join. Related:

- [Split column into multiple rows in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419993/split-column-into-multiple-rows-in-postgres/29420035#29420035)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

To *search* for particular tags:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posthistory
WHERE  tags LIKE '%<security>%'
AND    tags LIKE '%<osx>%';
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4bb5/3)

Applied to your search in T-SQL in our data explorer:

```
SELECT TOP 100
       PostId, UserId, Text AS Tags FROM PostHistory
WHERE  year(CreationDate) = 2011
AND    PostHistoryTypeId IN (3  -- initial tags
                           , 6  -- edit tags
                           , 9) -- rollback tags
AND    Text LIKE ('%<' + ##TagName:String?postgresql## + '>%');
```

(T-SQL syntax uses the non-standard `+` instead of `||`.)
https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/edit/417055

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the data to the relevant column only and called it `tags` to present the example.

Sample data

```
create table posthistory(tags text);
insert into posthistory values
  ('<lion><backup><time-machine>'),
  ('<spotlight><alfred><photo-booth>'),
  ('<lion><pdf><preview>'),
  ('<pdf>'),
  ('<asd>');
```

Query to get unique list of tags

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  unnest(
    regexp_split_to_array(
      trim('><' from tags), '><'
    )
  )
FROM
  posthistory
```

First we're removing all occurences of leading and trailing `>` and `<` signs from each row, then using `regexp_split_to_array()` function to get values into arrays, and then `unnest()` to expand an array to a set of rows. Finally `DISTINCT` eliminates duplicate values.

Presenting <kbd>**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/36251/2)**</kbd> to preview how it works.