# postgres 9.4 split column on multiple delimiters to new columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Referencing this SO question

[Postgres unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420035/461887)

Is there a way to split a column based on 2 delimiters into 4 columns?

If I have a column with this data in it.

```
11-3-1-4 $72390.00
```

How would I make it

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
11      3       1       4       72390.00
```

Plus should I retain the original column ?

Answer (score 1):

`string_to_array()` can be used for this:

```
select c1[1] as col1, 
       c1[2] as col2, 
       c1[3] as col3,
       c1[4] as col4,
       substr(col5, 2) as col5
from (
   select string_to_array((string_to_array(the_column, ' '))[1], '-') as c1,
          (string_to_array(the_column, ' '))[2] as col5
   from the_table
) t
```