# Using text in pl/pgsql brings empty set of results

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-queries, postgresql-10

I am new to pl/pgsql and trying to create a dynamic query. What I have now is  a basic combination of parameters for testing. When it works properly, I will gradually add more dynamic parts, to create a dynamic, all-in-one query.

The problem is that this should work, but instead I see an empty `search_creator` as Data Output in the pgadmin4. This is the code

```
CREATE  FUNCTION search_creator(creator text)
  RETURNS TABLE(place_id bigint, place_geom geometry, event_name character(200)) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
    'SELECT place.id, place.geom, event.name
     FROM person
     JOIN event_creator ON event_creator.person_id = person.id
     JOIN event ON event.id = event_creator.event_id
     JOIN cep ON cep.event_id = event.id
     JOIN place ON place.id = cep.place_id
     WHERE person.name LIKE $1'
    USING creator;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is how I call the function `select search_creator('mike');`.

If it helps, in the database, the `person.id` column is type `character(200)`.

If it helps, when I modify the function to accept `int` as input and alter the `WHERE` part to `WHERE person.id = $1` , then it works fine. I can see actual results in the pgadmin output.

What is wrong with my text variables? Is it the syntax?

Also, how can I do something like `WHERE person.name LIKE '%$1%'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run

```
SELECT search_creator('mike');
```

the function will execute

```
SELECT ... WHERE person.name LIKE 'mike'
```

which is identical to

```
SELECT ... WHERE person.name = 'mike'
```

Obviously there is no such record.

To prepend and append `%`, you could use

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ...
         WHERE person.name LIKE ' || quote_nullable('%' || creator || '%');
```

Comment: No, the problem is that is the record exists. I have a few data in the database and I can see a person with name `mike`. So its something else,I guess the formatting with `EXECUTE`?

Comment: I don't believe that. Perhaps a space somewhere, perhaps unprintable characters. You could cast the name to `bytea` and see which bytes are there. If it is `mike`, you should see `\x6d696b65`.

Comment: Actually all persons have names like `mike johnson`. I dont know if this makes any difference. If I try `WHERE person.name = mike johnson'`, it works fine. Should I change the column type in the database, from `character` to `text` or `varchar` ?

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. `'mike' <> 'mike johnson'`.

Comment: OK, I thought that `LIKE` will ignore this difference. I will try replacing everything with `varchar` then

Comment: That won't make a difference. You have to use `_` and `%` for wildcards. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I tested with `varchar` and `character` and there is no difference. The problem is the wildcards. I tried a LIKE with `%` but not `quote_nullable`, but I was getting errors, so this is why I asked in the first place. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi again Laurenz, sorry for bothering you, I have one last question. `plpgsql` is really hard and the learning curve is huge. Thanks for your overall help and patient. Do you have any tutorial or series of articles that explain `plpgsql` step by step, using examples? If so, please share so I can study from zero and understand, that would be better than me asking random stuff around and not making progress. The postgresql documentation is somewhat confusing. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know any information source except the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> This is how I call the function `select search_creator('mike');`

Since the function returns a *set* (SRF, set-returning function), call it with:

```
SELECT * FROM search_creator('mike');
```

> If it helps, in the database, the person.id column is type `character(200)`.

It helps. And it hurts. Like I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372364/syntax-error-in-dynamic-sql-in-pl-pgsql-function/48374384#comment83760467_48374384), you do not want to use `char(n)` (`character(n)`). Ever. (Also fix your table.) Read this:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

> Also, how can I do something like `WHERE person.name LIKE '%$1%'`?

Various techniques, but you can simplify with the regular expression match operator `~`, which does the same without leading and trailing wildcard - *almost*; special characters need to be treated separately for either operator:

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_creator(_creator text)
  RETURNS TABLE(place_id bigint, place_geom geometry, event_name text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
   'SELECT pl.id, pl.geom, e.name
    FROM   person        pe
    JOIN   event_creator ec ON ec.person_id = pe.id
    JOIN   event         e  ON e.id = ec.event_id
    JOIN   cep           c  ON c.event_id = e.id
    JOIN   place         pl ON pl.id = c.place_id
    WHERE  pe.name ~ $1'  -- note the operator: ~
   USING $1;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See:

- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)
- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)
- [PostgreSQL Reverse LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738114/postgresql-reverse-like/45740280#45740280)

Follow and read the linked answers and contained references to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

below is some working example (Iusednamed IN variables of instead numeric referencing, and `format` with `concat('%',t,'%')` to build LIKE query:

```
t=# create or replace function fa(t text) returns table (c text) as
$$
begin
return query execute format($q$select %L::text where 'test' like %L $q$,t,concat('%',t,'%'));
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 4.412 ms
t=# select * from fa('es');
 c
----
 es
(1 row)
```