# Extract multiple values from a string for each id

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

I want to extract matches from a string column for each id. How can I achieve that?

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+
|   id   |                 text                  |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
| fsaf12 | Other Questions,Missing Document      |
| sfas11 | Others,Missing Address,Missing Name   |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+--------+------------------+
|   id   |    extracted     |
+--------+------------------+
| fsaf12 | Other Questions  |
| fsaf12 | Missing Document |
| sfas11 | Others           |
| sfas11 | Missing Address  |
| sfas11 | Missing Name     |
+--------+------------------+
```

Here is the query for sample data: [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a654db21a869cc9fb4328357bc92bfeb)

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted. This looks easy but a bit tricky for new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_split_to_table` for your requirement like below:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT 'fsaf12' AS id, 'Other Questions,Missing Document' AS text UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sfas11', 'Others,Missing Address,Missing Name'
)
SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(text,',')
FROM t1
```

OUTPUT

```
| id        | extracted             |
|-----------|-----------------------|
| fsaf12    | Other Questions       |
| fsaf12    | Missing Document      |
| sfas11    | Others                |
| sfas11    | Missing Address       |
| sfas11    | Missing Name          |
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=71628b90c17390df98800d85c3f0e383)

Answer (score 1):

`Postgres` is not my forte at all but based on this [older](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56102413/9758194) post on SO you could try to use `unnest()`. I included a `TRIM()` to remove possible railing spaces after a split:

```
SELECT id, TRIM(unnest(string_to_array(text, ','))) as "extracted" FROM t1;
```

Or, if you want to use `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(text, '\s*,\s*') as "extracted" FROM t1;
```

Here we matches 0+ whitespace characters, a literal comma and again 0+ whitespace characters.

[image]