# Unnest row in PostgreSQL and include count of unnesting occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested

Following on from Matt's answer in: [Split column into multiple rows in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419993/split-column-into-multiple-rows-in-postgres)

I want to unnest a row into multiple rows based on a character in a cell, however I also want to include a count column containing the number of times a row was unnested.

I want this:

```
       name            |  id
-----------------------+------
 alpha, bravo, charlie |    1
 yankee, xray          |    2
 hotel                 |    3 
 indigo                |    4
```

to become this:

```
       name            |  id  | count
-----------------------+------+-------
 alpha                 |    1 |   3
 bravo                 |    1 |   3
 charlie               |    1 |   3
 yankee                |    2 |   2
 xray                  |    2 |   2
 hotel                 |    3 |   1
 indigo                |    4 |   1
```

The initial unnest query would be:

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(name, ', ')) as name, id
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `cross join` with regex:

```
select k, t.id, cardinality(regexp_split_to_array(t.name, ', ')) 
from tbl t cross join regexp_split_to_table(t.name, ', ') k
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1b54ef1e73d465016d43c00543f35843).