# How to split or divide columns with multiple values separated by a comma into individual rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, delimiter

Current Result

| ID | Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 257 | 10007,10135,10136 |
| 249 | 10026,10137,10326 |
| 251 | 10029 |
| 3293 | 100502,100551 |

I would like to convert these multiple orders into individual rows in POSTGRES

Required Result

| ID | Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 257 | 10007 |
| 257 | 10135 |
| 257 | 10136 |
| 249 | 10026 |
| 249 | 10137 |
| 249 | 10326 |
| 251 | 10029 |
| 3293 | 100502 |
| 3293 | 100551 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split column into multiple rows in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419993/split-column-into-multiple-rows-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for you problem:

```
SELECT ID,UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(Orders, ',')) Orders
FROM Table1;
```

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c5d6099cf1edf595ce6b8a3f3456594)

**Unnest**: It is an array function which expands an array into set of rows.

Syntax:

```
unnest ( anyarray )
```

**string_to_array**:
It is also an array function which splits string into array elements using supplied delimiter and optional null-string.

Here optional null-string parameter is used to replace the sub-strings in the input which matches the null-string parameter value with NULL value in the output or final array.

Syntax:

```
string_to_array(text, text [, text])
```

For more information on `unnest` and `string_to_array` syntax follow the below link:

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-array.html

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert comma-separated text to array and use unnest function:

```
SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array[orders], ',')) FROM your_table;
```